# Converting between pandas and geopandas without preserving 'geometry' column restrictions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, geometry, geopandas

I have a `geopandas` df which has `'geometry'` column. Apperently `'geometry'` column is a special column in `geopandas` dfs. I can add either a `BaseGeometry` or `None` values to the `'geometry'` column.

```
gdf
            name  ...                   geometry
0     Storages_0  ...   POINT (9.34153 47.90014)
1     Storages_1  ...  POINT (12.48775 48.04216)
2     Storages_2  ...  POINT (12.14856 47.95684)
3     Storages_3  ...  POINT (12.58845 48.14799)
4     Storages_4  ...   POINT (8.64394 49.42888)
...          ...  ...                        ...
4318      N_4059  ...   POINT (1.84378 59.00563)
4319      N_4060  ...   POINT (2.20207 59.15696)
4320      N_4061  ...   POINT (3.06887 60.10174)
4321      N_4062  ...   POINT (3.01948 60.06188)
4322      N_4063  ...   POINT (2.33806 59.46650)
[4323 rows x 7 columns]
```

To remove this restriction I convert the `gdf` into a `pandas` df via `pd.DataFrame(gdf.copy())`.
I use `.copy()`, so that the changes I do in `df`, wont effect `gdf`. However I still cannot change the `'geometry'` column of `df`, even though it is not a `geopandas` df.

I can maybe convert the `geopandas` df to dict, and then create the `pandas` df via `.from_dict()`. However I do not want to do this, since it is unneccessary convertion.

What else can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Geometry-type column is geopandas (no matter how it is called) uses GeometryArray under the hood, that allows you to save only geometry object or None.

You can convert GeometryArray of geometry dtype to an array the `object` dtype that does lift these restrictions but does not give you access to geometry operations.

```py
as_object = df.geometry.astype(object)
```